# When relating Java objects, you must have a list of the Java Object it is related to?

Tags: java, object, jpa, entity-relationship

So I'm working on a project that encompasses Java/JPA and a relational database.

Lets say you have a Branch class and a `BranchService` class. Branch contains all the fields relevant to Branch and `BranchService` contains all the things relevant to `BranchService`. If you were to disregard the JPA aspect of the project, and you were to create a new Branch object in Java, the Branch class needs to contain a List of `BranchService` to maintain the relationship between the two classes.

I understand some of the logic behind this. If you take away the JPA and the rdbms, there is nothing to relate these two tables. I don't understand why this connection needs to be via a List, and I also am a little unsure of the syntax. Am I just adding this to the end of my Branch class?

```
List<BranchService> bsList = new ArrayList<BranchService>();
```

If tried searching online for examples of this, but I can't find any examples. Possibly because I'm not 100% on what to look for.. Grateful for an explanation for all this or any material I could read.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here. And if you don't know how to create a List instance, then you should practice with basic Java exercises before using JPA, which is a complex framework.

Comment: Please clarify your questions. Relationships do not only work through `List`, `List` is for `1-N` relationships that keep an order. You could do as well `BranchService bService = new BranchService()`.

Comment: It feels like you have relational database background and "think in tables". Try to get rid of that if you want to work in an object oriented way.

Comment: It stands for one-to-many relationship, you should buy the book on JPA or any other ORM framework that would better describe the consensus.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. So using a List is specific to muiltiplicity. If it was a 1-1 relationship, I would just create an instance of the BranchService and because it is 1-N I am creating a List as Branch can have many branch services. I feel I understand that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your question right this is not an issue of Java or JPA but an issue of the object  model: If a branch service is a part of a branch then the branch should have a reference of every brach service it contains, e.g. in a Collection or List (and likewise the branch entity in the database should contain the foreign key to the branch service). If a branch service is not a part of the branch then the branch should not necessarily contain a reference to the branch service (but this may be useful for fast navigation).

In the latter case it is only necessary that you are able to identify the relationship between a branch and branch services - you can navigate from one to the other by means of existing objects or data (there may be a reference in one of them or there may be a third entity which knows about that relationship, etc.).

I would recommend to read about object modelling and object relational mapping (O/R mapping).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to do things.
But typically your `Branch` class wouldn't know anything abou the BranchService. Instead, whenever you want to do something your application would do something like: `branchService.save(myBranchInstance);`

I don't know why you'd want to relate the `Branch` to the `BranchService`

Answer (score 1):

This is the example of one to many relationship. one "Branch" can have multiple "BranchService". so the Branch class contain a List of BranchService, it is to maintain the relationship(one to many relationship) between the two classes

Read example of

- one to one
- one to many
- many to many

you will understand relationship type

one to many example
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I understand it now. I am creating a List of BranchService in Branch as it is mirroring the multiplicity of the relationship. If it was a one to one, I'd simply instantiate BranchService in my Branch class. Is this correct?